# make it a point

Tags: word-meaning

> All laboratory employees make it a point to take every precaution to avoid potential hazards.

I tried to find the meaning of the phrase *make it a point* but only found *make a point of doing st* in Cambridge Dictionary. My first question is, are they the same? Cambridge says *make a point of doing st* is *always* or *take great care to do st*, the latter seems suitable for my example above.[link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-a-point-of-doing-sth)

However, there is another source that tells differently. [link] (http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/point) This dictionary says that the meaning is paying attention to st to make sure it happen. I also read some other posts on English forums and they mentioned *make sure* as well. So, I felt like the phrase *make a point of doing st* of Cambridge is somehow irrelevant. Am I right? If yes, the meaning that Learner's Dictionary tells me is true?

Comment: How do you think the Cambridge definition might be irrelevant?

Comment: Assuming when you say "st" you mean "something", the laboratory employees *are* making a point of doing something, where "something" is "taking every precaution".

Answer (score 1):

Both definitions are actually telling you the same thing but using different wording.

> to make it a point

is

> to make sure

something happens by focussing on it or giving it great care/focus/attention to make sure it "always" happens.

Comment: To be honest is a fairly empty phrase in terms of meaning in my opinion, but I agree that this is the correct sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

Accordint to [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20it%20a%20point%20to%20(do%20something)):

> ## make it a point to (do something)
>
> to give one's attention to (doing something) **to make sure that it happens**.
>
> *She makes it a point to treat her employees fairly.*

In the above example, she (probably the boss) is trying to be fair with every employee as much as possible.

In your example, all employees are trying to be very careful about avoiding potential hazards by taking every precaution that they can possibly think of.